# Call two fetch function with setState in between

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am trying to call two fetch APIs to store the information.

After first API call to cloudinary I get the URL back, which I want to store in state before hitting second API to store info in database. I am getting setAddOnData undefined error. While I try to make second API call , code functions properly for single API

```
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(fileInputRef.current.files[0]);
    const myNewCroppedFile = fileInputRef.current.files[0];

    console.log(myNewCroppedFile);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', myNewCroppedFile);
    formData.append('upload_preset', 'xprl6rwq');
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    };

    const addOnBody = JSON.stringify({ itemName, itemIconURL, itemPrice });

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'
      }
    };

    const option2 = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: addOnBody
    };

    return fetch(
      'https://api.Cloudinary.com/v1_1/antilibrary/image/upload',
      options
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res =>
        setAddOnData({
          ...addOnData,
          itemIconURL: res.secure_url
        })
      )
      .then(fetch(`/api/v1/addOn`, option2, config))
      .then(res => res.json());
  };
```

```
  const [addOnData, setAddOnData] = useState({
    addOnCategory: '',
    itemName: '',
    itemPrice: '',
    itemIconURL: '',
    itemIconFileName: '',
    step: 1
  });
```

Comment: You need to define `setAddOnData` before `onSubmit` in your code. What is the order now?

Comment: Hello..It is before onSubmit

Comment: `.then(fetch('/api/v1/addOn', option2, config))` will fetch before `setAddOnData` is called, is that the intent?

Comment: Can you add the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: Just one note. Your second fetch call is missing the arrow function.

.then(() => fetch(`/api/v1/addOn`, option2, config))
      .then(res => res.json());

Also

Comment: Hey Kevin,,I need to call .then(fetch('/api/v1/addOn', option2, config)) after setrAddOnData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState calls are asynchronous.  When you run your second fetch call, the `setAddOnData` hasn't necessarily updated the `addonData` variable yet.  You'd be best off moving the second fetch call to a `useEffect` which is dependent on the data returned from your first fetch call.

```js
  const addOnBody = JSON.stringify({ itemName, itemIconURL, itemPrice });

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'
    }
  };

  const option2 = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: addOnBody
  };


  const onSubmit = e => {
 
    ...

    return fetch(
      'https://api.Cloudinary.com/v1_1/antilibrary/image/upload',
      options
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res =>
        setAddOnData({
          ...addOnData,
          itemIconURL: res.secure_url
        })
      )

  };

  useEffect( () => {

    fetch(`/api/v1/addOn`, option2, config)
      .then(res => res.json());

  },[addOnData.itemIconURL])
```

Comment: Hi Sethh,..Not working req.body for API call is empty object..

Comment: Here is the implemetation
  useEffect(() => {
    const addOnBody = JSON.stringify({ itemName, itemIconURL, itemPrice });

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'
      }
    };

    const option2 = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: addOnBody
    };

    fetch(`/api/v1/addOn`, option2, config).then(res => res.json());
  }, [itemIconURL]);

Comment: Right...the `option2` and `config` and `addOnBody` variables were all inside your `onSubmit` function, so not available within the scope of the `useEffect`.  I moved them outside of that function scope so the `useEffect` can get to them.  See the edited answer.

Comment: Just a little help I need with request body {method: "POST", body: "{"itemName":"jj","itemIconURL":"https://res.cloudi…e/upload/v1593282041/bacon.png","itemPrice":"78"}"}

Comment: Currently it looks like this and is giving me 500 error

Comment: {
    "itemName":"Cheese",
    "itemPrice":"30",
    "itemIconURL":"https://res.cloudinary.com/antilibrary/image/upload/v1593326405/Piatto/Icons/cheese_cicwad.svg"
} this is expected body

Comment: [500 errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) are typically on the server-end...so there's something wrong with the endpoint you're trying to reach.  either your url is bad or their servers are having problems.  Also, if this answer helped you, upvote it.  Everyone loves meaningless internet points